# Dropdown menus. Complete beginner, out of my depth, save me

Tags: php, html

so I am trying to edit my website to include a drop down menu. I have created the drop down but I need to link it so that when I click the 'add to cart' button (which redirects to a checkout), the option selected is remembered so I can see it. Really looking for a place to start since im a bit lost beyond this point. Thanks in advance

```
<form action="/action_page.php">   
<select>
<option value="Childrens Small">Childrens Small</option>
<option value="Childrens Medium">Childrens Medium</option>
<option value="Childrens Large">Childrens Large</option>
<option value="Adult Small">Adult Small</option>
<option value="Adult Medium">Adult Medium</option>
<option value="Adult Large">Adult Large</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: The `<select>` tag needs a name if you want to submit the form. See http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: This goes back to core of web development. This does NOT fit to SO question requirements as far as I know.

Comment: I sort of agree with you but people also come here to learn and SO is known as a place to ask questions about all things related to any kind of development. I've always felt it better to answer if possible and worry about how well it fits as a secondary concern. Just my $0.02 worth.

Comment: Sorry! I didnt know where else to come. Thank you for the help though, i'll remember to take my stupid questions somewhere more appropriate next time :)

Comment: phpfreaks is a good forum for beginner questions.  They are very patient there and  the format is more forgiving of questions like this one.  The biggest issue with your question is that it's really about form handling and has nothing to do with a drop down menu.  Drop down menus are for navigation, not form submission, and typically will be handled differently.

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML would look like this:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">   
<select name="size_selected">
<option value="Childrens Small">Childrens Small</option>
<option value="Childrens Medium">Childrens Medium</option>
<option value="Childrens Large">Childrens Large</option>
<option value="Adult Small">Adult Small</option>
<option value="Adult Medium">Adult Medium</option>
<option value="Adult Large">Adult Large</option>
</select>
</form>
```

In your PHP program you would then refer to the value selected as $_POST['size_selected'] (or whatever you named the select field using name="").

If you prefer using GET. Then change the method to method="get" and refer to the value as "$_GET['size_selected']

Comment: This answers the question.  I might add that this information as well as a few wrinklies is in [the PHP manual here](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).   Every new PHP developer should read that section as well as the one of [Handling File Uploads](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php), as they are well explained and provide a solid foundation for form handling.

Comment: @gview I agree. Especially with the file upload documentation. It is fairly well misunderstood by a lot of new developers.